# How to check JWT integrity without secret key in PHP?

Tags: php, security, jwt

I develop an application that uses some JWT tokens not generated by it. So far, I store tokens and strictly compare the token given in header with the one I got in database.

All JWT PHP libraries I found show examples in this order :

1. Generate token with a secret ky
2. Decode JWT with this key

My need would be to check that the JWT is valid (regarding to header, payload and signature given) that would add a security layer.

How can I "simply" check the token integrity without having the secret key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWTs can be either *encrypted* or *signed* (or both, sequentially), using either *symmetric* or *asymmetric* algorithms.

The process you describe uses a *symmetric* algorithm, where the same key is used to sign or encrypt the token, and then to verify or decrypt it. This would be appropriate for tokens that are being created and consumed by the same application - for instance, a web app sending a token to the browser, and reading it back from the request.

If one application is creating the token to be used by a different one, it should use an *asymmetric* algorithm:

- To *encrypt* something, you take a *public key*, apply the encryption algorithm, and end up with a string that can only be *decrypted* with the *private key*. A common analogy is that the public key acts like a padlock: anyone can snap it shut, but only the holder of the private key can open it afterwards.
- To *sign* something, you take a *private* key, apply the signing algorithm, and end up with a message readable by anybody, and *verifiable* by anyone with the *public* key. The analogy is that the public key is like a sample of someone's signature: it's not sufficient to forge their signature, but it is sufficient to tell if a signature is real.

In your case, you need the application generating the token to *sign* it using a private key, which only that application knows. The corresponding *public* key can then be shared to every user of the service, and stored in the configuration of the application that needs to verify the token.

You don't specify what library you're using, so it's hard to be specific, but what you need to look for is the option to *sign* your token rather than *encrypt* it. Then you (or whoever controls the other application) distribute the *public* key to every endpoint that needs to verify it, and verify that it contains a signature with the expected algorithm and key.

For instance, using [the `lcobucci/jwt` library](https://packagist.org/packages/lcobucci/jwt), the application creating the token would look like this:

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;

$signer = new Sha256();
$privateKey = new Key('file://{path to your private key}');

$token = (new Builder())->withClaim('some', 'claim')
                        ->getToken($signer,  $privateKey);
```

and the application receiving it would verify it like this:

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;

$publicKey = new Key('file://{path to your public key}');

$token = (new Parser())->parse('{token taken from request}');
if ( $token->verify($signer, $publicKey) ) {
    var_dump($token->getClaims());
}
else {
    echo 'Token does not have valid signature!';
}
```

---

As an aside, if you're checking tokens against a known list in a database, you don't really need JWT, you can just use something like a GUID and store the extra data against that in the database. The idea of a JWT is that you don't need any prior knowledge, and rely on checking the signature and the claims inside the token (e.g. using an "expires at" claim to avoid an attacker reusing an old token they found in logs). This trades off the length and complexity of the token for allowing a decentralized and stateless application to read the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Please find my snippet to decode the payload without keys and without any libraries, simple php code.

```
function decodeJWTPayloadOnly($token){
        $tks = explode('.', $token);
        if (count($tks) != 3) {
            return null;
        }
        list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
        $input=$bodyb64;
        $remainder = strlen($input) % 4;
        if ($remainder) {
            $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
            $input .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
        }
        $input = (base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/')));

        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') && !(defined('JSON_C_VERSION') && PHP_INT_SIZE > 4)) {
            $obj = json_decode($input, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
        } else {
            $max_int_length = strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) - 1;
            $json_without_bigints = preg_replace('/:\s*(-?\d{'.$max_int_length.',})/', ': "$1"', $input);
            $obj = json_decode($json_without_bigints);
        }
        return $obj;
}
```

Comment: Why you want to reinvent the wheel and do the JWT by yourself?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: this NOT SAFE! it may decode your jwt - but it does not validate it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I "simply" check the token integrity without having the secret key?

Assuming that the question means that you simply don't have access to any kind of public key (in case a asymmetric signature algorithm was used) or a secret (in case of symmetric algorithms), the answer is:

You can't!

The signature is a hash, calculated from the values of your header + payload + secret/key. Verification basically means to recalculate that hash and compare with the signature of the token. If you don't have the key or secret, you can't calculate the hash and therefore not proof that the signature matches the content or not.

You didn't go into detail about the use case, the roles of the token issuer and your application. But if you want to verify a token that was issued by a third party authentication system, it uses a asymmetric algorthm and you might find a key id (`kid`) and the url of a JWK (JSON Web Key) endpoint in the token, from which you can obtain the public key in form of a JWK.

And, if you just want to read the contents of the token, assuming that you're talking about signed (not encrypted) tokens, you can however asccess the content by simply decoding it. Header and payload are just Base64url encoded. You don't need a key to decode them.

Comment: As I explained at length in my answer on this page, asymmetric key cryptography has solved this use case long ago: anyone can verify with the public key, which doesn't need to be secret in any way.

Comment: his question is about verification without a secret or key (it don't see where he specified symmetric or asymmetric algorithms, he wrote "secret key", not "private key"!). With NO key he can't verify, right? Please read the question and my answer again.

Comment: and actually I read your answer before I wrote mine and only answered because I thought you might have misinterpreted the question. I hope the OP can clarify what he really meant.

Comment: "Secret key" and "private key" mean the same thing, because a public key, by definition, is not "secret" - anyone who wants to verify the token can have a copy and share it at will.

Comment: And for symmetric algorithms like HS256 the term "secret" or "secret key" is used, even if it's not a key.  And I would generally not assume that terms are always used with highest precision. It's your interpretation of the question, that's fine but I guess the OP is not that much an expert in crypto terms to make that fine distinction.  BTW, I even mentioned public key verification via JWK.

Comment: I added a line to make my interpreation of the OPs question clear.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but I still think your explanation is misleading, because if they _are_ using "secret key" wrong, your answer doesn't correct them. If the JWT is signed using an asymmetric algorithm, your explanation of the signature is wrong, and if it's not, then the mention of JWK is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't read the OPs mind and answer for two possible cases. Basically I assume he just wants to verify a token either has no access to a secret or key (of whatever kind) or he might have access via JWK but don't know about it yet because he's unaware of that mechanism.

Comment: But those aren't the only two possibilities. I'd never heard of JWK before, but have seen plenty of services where the public key is distributed as part of the documentation or sign-up process. Even if there is a JWK, you need to know whether to trust it, so it comes to the same thing (check the documentation). I've updated my answer to mention symmetric keys more explicitly, because without understanding that, the OP can't ever know the answer themselves.

Comment: regarding JWK here's a good read for you: [Amazon (AWS) uses JWK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html), for example

Comment: Thanks. So it does basically come down to the same thing as the public key being in the documentation / sign-up process, since it's a one-off process to configure your application. My main point was that you need to understand the difference between a secret key and a public key before looking at anything specific like a JWK. Your answer just glosses over that, using "secret / key" as though they're interchangeable terms, which I think is unhelpful.

Comment: You're welcome. I understand the difference and I still think that the OP has a simple question and most of the assumptions go a bit over the top. Sure, it's not wrong to go deeper in the answer and explain different mechanisms but it seems beyond the scope of the question. It's also interesting that in the beginning you wanted to tell me that the OP of course talks about asymmetric algorithms and private (secret) keys and now you think he described a symmetric algorithm. I think best would have been to close vote "needs details for clarity", because this is what certainly is lacking.

Comment: We simply know nothing about where the token comes from, if he has any influence, what's the actual usecase, what's the role off his application and so on. It's all speculation.